# UIAlertView on iPhone with 2 buttons. How to make them both look the same?

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I'm using this code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[alert setTitle:@"Select Tutorial"];
[alert setMessage:@""];
[alert setDelegate:self];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Basic"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Advanced"];
alert.tag = e_VTselecttutorial;
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

It produces a window with two buttons, and it all works the way I want except for a graphic problem. Neither button is preferred, and the Advanced button comes up highlighted. It's like it thinks Basic is a Cancel button, and Advanced is an OK button. I've checked cancelButtonIndex, and it's -1 as I expect.

I want both buttons to look the same, and I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combine everything into one line you can do so much easier.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Tutorial" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Basic", @"Advanced", nil];
```

Have you looked at an Action Sheet for this?  According to the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ModalViews/ModalViews.html):

> Alerts give people important information that affects their use of the application (or the device). The arrival of an alert is usually unexpected, because it generally tells people about a problem or a change in the current situation that might require them to take action.
>
> Action sheets give people additional choices related to the action they are currently taking. People learn to expect the appearance of an action sheet when they tap a toolbar button that begins either a potentially destructive action (such as deleting all recent calls) or an action that can be completed in different ways (such as a send action for which users can specify one of several destinations).

Comment: Just set up the ActionSheet. Just what I needed. Thanks!